# Where could I find a list of IP address that belong to paid VPN networks?

Tags: blacklist, vpn

I would like to know if there is a list of known IP addresses that belong to paid VPN services, such as HideMyAss or PureVPN.

**EDIT**

I am looking for this because I am tracking votes by IP address and am getting fraudulent votes through services like HideMyAss or PureVPN.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say you won't find a list specifically informing you which HideMyAss or PureVPN IP addresses are banned since these services do not publish the blocks of IP's they purchase. They are also forever increasing the amount of IP's they have on their network.

The only advice you will be able to get on this topic is that when you purchase such as service you gain access to multiple servers in multiple regions which in effect if you experience a block you can jump over to a new server.

Additional you can check if an IP is blocked using:

- [IP Finder](http://ip-finder.me/)
- [IP Blacklist Cloud](http://www.dnsbl.info/dnsbl-database-check.php)

**Running your own VPN**

If you want assurance that the IP you use will not be banned at any stage on a site(s) that you use then you can install your own VPN service on a [VPS using OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/index.php/download.html) which is free for up to 2 connections. By exclusively using a static IP that is only used by yourself would be the best method to avoid uninterpreted services.

I run my own VPN using a 128mb RAM VPS by [Cloud Shards](http://www.cloudshards.com) which only cost me $16 for the year, so in terms of pricing running your own VPN is by far 'cheaper and faster' than most VPN providers.

Comment: Actually, I was looking for this list more for banning users who are using these services.  I have a site where users can vote on contest entries, tracked by IP address, but there are people selling votes. I tracked these vote's IP addresses back to hosting companies all over the world and that leads me to believe that VPN companies are being used.  I know HMA uses various hosting companies for their servers because I have tracked a few of their IP addresses.  But the information you provided remains the same regardless.  Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that VPN's are expanding all the time and some add 1,000's of new ips each month. Your best of addressing the issue of people able to vote without registration (Which I'm just guessing is the case) - Let me know.

Comment: And your best of blocking hostname, not IP. so *@*rackspace.com for example Since these VPN's are issued IP in blocks and can vary dramaticly they never use their own host name as far as I've used them so your best of blocking whoever is issuing their blocks, Normally VPS providers.